# PHP redirect from index.php when you're logged in

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I'm trying to have login confirmation at the top of my pages so if you're on the login page and you're already logged in it will redirect you to the home page of the website. And if you try to go to the home page of the website when you're not logged in, it redirects you to the index.

index.php - code for login

```
if(isset($_POST['submitLogin'])) {
    $emailLogin = $_POST['emailA'];
    $passwordLogin = md5($_POST['passwordA']);

    $loginQuery = "SELECT email,password FROM account WHERE email='" . $emailLogin . "' AND    password='" . $passwordLogin . "'";    
    $loginResult = mysql_query($loginQuery);
    $admin_row = mysql_fetch_array($loginResult);

    if (mysql_num_rows($loginResult ) == 1) { 
        session_start();
        $getemail=$admin_row['email'];
        $getpass=$admin_row['password'];
        //session_register("uname");
        $_SESSION['logged_user']=$getemail;
        $_SESSION['logged_pass']=$getpass;
        header("Location: grocery.php?foodGroup=Dairy%20and%20Egg%20Products");
    }
    else {
        $loginErrorMessage = "";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
```

index.php - checks if you're logged in (at the top of the page)

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
    header("Location: grocery.php?foodGroup=Dairy and Egg Products");
} else {
    print "Error: Login is not set";
}
```

grocery.php - checks if you're logged in (at the top of the page)

```
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    print "Error: Login is not set";
}
```

When I try to log into the page I keep getting "Error: Login is not set". I need help with how to get the variable to go to grocery.php as well as being able to tell if I'm logged in on the index so I can redirect the user to the home page (grocery.txt).

Thank you

Comment: Try using `session_start()` prior to setting session variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Every Page where you need to get or set $_SESSION varaibles you need to first call session_start function before performing any operations with theses variables

so edit this code and add session start method above

```
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
header("Location: index.php");
} else {
print "Error: Login is not set";
 }
```